# T-SQL creating variables within a larger SELECT statement? Is there a quicker way?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Let's say I have the world's 2 simplest tables as my data:

The first table looks like this:

[image]

The second table looks like this:

[image]

Then let's say I have the following statement in T-SQL

```
SELECT  
    T1.Column1 + T2.Column1 AS 'AddedColumns'
FROM 
    Table1 AS T1, Table2 AS T2
```

So my result should display a single column with values : 6 and 9 that I have aliased as "AddedColumns"

Let's say for the sake of argument I wanted to add Column 2 from Table 1 to "Added Columns" how would I do that?

One way I understand is to declare variables at the top, but that would require reproducing the SELECT, FROM and crucially the WHERE statements that I tag on. Is there a way to just do something like:

```
SELECT  
    T1.Column1 + T2.Column AS 'AddedColumns',
    'AddedColumns' + T2.Column2 AS 'Double Added'
FROM 
    Table1 AS T1, Table2 AS T2
```

Or do I just have to do something like:

```
Declare @NewVariable Int = SELECT (..... FROM ....... WHERE......)
```

At the very top for every variable I wish to store?

Comment: `SELECT  
T1.Column1+T2.Column AS 'AddedColumns'

FROM Table1 AS T1, Table2 AS T2 `  shouldn't that read `T2.Column1`?

Comment: @JonathanWilson yes good catch, thank you. It's not a real query but an example one I made so I didn't run it to see if it worked. Ty

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: that first query would actually produce `6`, `9`, `9`, and `12`... four results, not two, because there was no limit placed on the join. It will create every possible combination of the two tables. And who still uses that obsolete `Table1, Table2` join syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross apply`:

```
SELECT v.AddedColumn,
       v.AddedColumn + T2.Column2 AS [Double Added]
FROM Table1 T1 CROSS JOIN
     Table2 T2 CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (T1.Column1 + T2.Column)) v(AddedColumn);
```

Some suggestions:

- Never use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I'll look into this, thank you. Also I appreciate your advice. Is there any particular reason for using double quotes for column aliases? I've always preferred implicit joins using WHERE, is there any particular disadvantage to doing so? It's just made logical sense, where as something about the Join syntax just always throws me off. You might be able to tell SQL is not exactly a strong suit for me

Comment: Column aliases do not require single or double quotes and so adding quotes just causes confusion and introduces potential for error. I'm pretty sure double quotes aren't used in SQL (unless in a string or possibly some dynamic sql). Explicit joins make the code more readable. To my knowledge, performance is not affected. Also note, CROSS APPLY is a different operation than a JOIN and has some performance benefits under certain scenarios

Comment: @JedBartlet Implicit joins using the WHERE clause have been obsolete for more than 25 years, ever since the ansi-92 standard came out. Practically no serious database person does their joins that way, and there are certain things you just can't express with the old syntax.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn got it. I'll stop using that, and start getting used to JOINs. I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's example is probably what you want but there is another feature of SQL that you might like to use called CTE -- CTE are sub-queries that you can re-use as a table. Consider the following code.

```
WITH table_a_and_square as
(
   SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col1*a.col1 as col1_sqr
   FROM tablea as a
), table_a_and_cube as
(
   SELECT col1, col1_sqr*col1_sqr as col1_cube
   FROM table_a_and_square 
)
SELECT ... -- a select statement with those two tables.
```

Some of the nice things about CTE

- you can have as many as you want there are no limits.  This makes it easy to break SQL code into smaller steps.
- since you can "end" at any point, when debugging I will put select statements in between CTE selects and just run that and everything above it to see if things are working up to that select.  This gives me a modular way to test.
- In most cases the compiler will take care of optimizations and using a CTE will be as fast or faster than larger queries.
- You can name the CTE selects -- this can help in documenting your code and making it easier to understand, support, and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply this?

```
SELECT  
    T1.Column1 + T2.Column1 AS 'AddedColumns',
    T1.Column1 + T2.Column1 + T2.Column2 AS 'Double Added'
FROM Table1 AS T1, Table2 AS T2
```

Comment: Jonathan I appreciate your response, this solution absolutely works, unfortunately the real table I'm working with is substantially more complicated and the calculations I'm performing are more numerous. There's about 25 steps/calculations I need to perform, so putting all that on one line is incredibly messy, in addition I need each of those 25 pieces as their own separate category/column if that makes sense. I used the examples above just to keep things simple, I understand that for the purposes of this fictional query your solution is 100% the sane thing to do

Comment: Consider posting an example that more closely resembles your actual dataset.  That way, you'll get better suggestions.

Comment: @JedBartlet If that's true, your table design is... well, it's not good.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Right.  Sounds like the real issue here is the design of that table. Jed, Wouldn't it be better to treat the root problem rather than a symptom?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn and Jonathan. The Table design for the actual table I'm using is actually ok, it's just that I'm using it for a purpose for which maybe it wasn't intended, hence my questions. I'm basically adding elements/components to the table to modify it, so in a way I am changing it. I'm also not very good SQL as you can tell, I'm honestly just surprised that I can't just create a temporary variable, but I guess SQL is designed for a different purpose obviously than say R. Also Just to be clear the example above is made up just meant to allow me to ask a question, that's why it's so silly

Comment: Jed, just post your actual table definition.  Your contrived example is clearly not helping anyone.

Comment: The basic principle behind what I'm trying to do to my dataset is basically the same. I'm trying to perform calculations (adding columns together etc) and I just want to able store those results and then access them so I figured this fictitious table would suffice. I can't really post the actual data set, as it contains some personal information. Maybe I can post a more complicated version with some made up numbers/data, I'll look into that.

Comment: Perhaps what you're after is the concept of derived tables.  Consider this tutorial: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1042/using-derived-tables-to-simplify-the-sql-server-query-process/